# Is it necessary to bring the primary key of non repeating table while normalizing the database from UNF to 1NF

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, oracle11g, normalization

My UNF is

```
database(
manager_id,
manager_name,
{supplier_id,
supplier_name,
{order_id,
order_quantity}}
{purchase_id,
purchase_date}
```

Here `manager_name`, `supplier_id`, `order_id` and `purchase_id` are primary key.
During normalization there will be 1 table called `purchase`. Is it necessary to make `manager_name` as a foreign key?

How can I normalize these database?

This is a part of my college project on database. Normalization is really confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider splitting things out by things that naturally go together. In this case you have manager information, supplier information, order information and purchase information. I personally would want to know the difference between an order and a purchase because that is not clear to me.

So you have at least four tables for those separate pieces of information  (although depending on the other fields you might need, suppliers and managers could be in the same table with an additional field such as person_type to distinguish them, in this case you would want a lookup table to grab the valid person type values from).  Then you need to see how these things relate to each other.  Are they in a one to one relationship or a one-to many or a many to many relationship? In a one-to one relationship, you need the FK to also have a unique constraint of index to maintain the uniqueness. In a many to many you will need an additional junction table that contains both ids.

Otherwise in the simplest case the child table of purchase would have FKs to the manager, supplier. and order tables.

Manager name should under no circumstances be a primary key. Many people have the same name. Use Manager ID as the key because it is unique where name is not. In general I prefer to separate out the names into First, middle and last so that you can sort on last name easily. However in some cultures this doesn't work so well.

Comment: That would be thank you, ma'am. Not all technical people are male.